# генератор случайных чисел в swift

Tags: swift, случайные-числа

Доброго всем дня/вечера/ночи

Изучаю swift, возникла проблема с генератором случайных чисел. До этого изучал php и там была такая функция `

> rand(мин. число, макс. число)

В swift я понял, что есть что-то вроде такой функции, но там указывается только последнее число.

Например типа этого

```
struct Randomizer {

    // return all types of random

    static func randomNum(num: Int) -> Int {

        let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(num)) + 1)

        return rand
    }

}
```

Randomizer.randomNum(23)

или это

```
#if os(Linux)
    import Glibc
    import SwiftShims
#else
    import Darwin
#endif

func cs_arc4random_uniform(upperBound: UInt32) -> UInt32 {  
    #if os(Linux)
        return _swift_stdlib_arc4random_uniform(upperBound)
    #else
        return arc4random_uniform(upperBound)
    #endif }
```

но это все равно не дает вывести число в определенном диапазоне например 30-120

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так укажите необходимый минимум. К примеру, если 30-120:

```
let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(num)) + 1) + 30
```

где `num = 120 - 30 = 90`

Если минимум меняется, передавайте какой должен быть:

```
static func randomNum(maxNum: Int, minNum: Int) -> Int {
    let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxNum-minNum)) + 1) + minNum
    return rand
}
```

Comment: интересно, почему епол сразу такой функционал не включили?

Answer (score 1):

```
let lower : UInt32 = 30
let upper : UInt32 = 120
let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform((upper - lower) + 1) + lower
```

Answer (score -1):

Самый простой способ задать случайное число:

```
let diceRoll = Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)
```